# Short sci-fi story about humans in a zoo in an alien spaceship

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Around 30 years ago, I read a book in Czechoslovakia (translated into Slovak) which was a collection of short science fiction stories.

I remember a particular story where an astronaut from Earth discovers a zoo on an alien ship.  Inside one of the cages, he finds a human. The story ended with an astronaut discovering another human in one of the cages, and asking the reader "What would you do if you were in my shoes?" translated from Slovak. I believe the story was called either "Galactic Zoo" or "The Zoo" by Alvin Levin?, but I haven't been able to find the book.

I was wondering if anyone recognizes this story or has any information about it that could help me locate it.

It's possible that this story was published alone or as part of a different collection in English speaking countries, and the specific parts mentioned may be different in the original before translation, but I'm interested specifically in this one.

Comment: Note:  I can't find a science fiction author by that name or a short story with that title that appears to fit the time frame and subject.

Comment: I'm afraid my reading diary was destroyed in a fire, we couldn't decipher much of the information in it. My brother and I both read this book and we believe the story was titled either "Galactic Zoo" or "The Zoo." translated from Slovak. However, we're not sure about the exact title, and we can't recall the author's name except for the fact that my brother thinks it might be Alvin. One detail we both remember is that the story ended with an astronaut discovering another human in one of the cages, and asking the reader "What would you do if you were in my shoes?" again translated from Slovak.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/shortscifistories/s/dngMnk5jPh - This is you, I presume.

Comment: You might want to check [the Encyclopedia of Science Fiction's Zoo entry](https://sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/zoo) and/or [TVTropes People Zoo](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PeopleZoo) but there aren't many entries there at the latter.